# replacing codes in string with values from database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on replacing some codes in string. I have a function which gets an email template from emailtemplates table with some codes like `##NewUserFirstName##` and `##password##`
 in body column of that table. There is another table which has defined what value from which table will replace these codes so for `##NewUserFirstName##` I have defined `UserProfile.FirstName` and for `##password##` `UserProfile.password` in second table. I have got all merge codes like this:

```
  using (IMailMergeCodeManager mailMergeCodeManager = new ManagerFactory().GetMailMergeCodeManager())
    {
        mailMergeCodes = mailMergeCodeManager.GetAll().ToList();
    }
```

Now I am replacing the codes in template with these codes like this:

```
 using (ICampaignManager campaignManager = new ManagerFactory().GetCampaignManager())
 {
     using (IUserProfileManager UserProfileManager1 = new ManagerFactory().GetUserProfileManager())
     {
         using (IAccountManager AccountManager = new ManagerFactory().GetAccountManager())
         {
             using (ICallTypeManager CallTypeManager = new ManagerFactory().GetCallTypeManager())
             {
                 using (ICallOutcomeManager CallOutComeManager = new ManagerFactory().GetCallOutcomeManager())
                 {
                     using (ICallRecordingManager CallRecordingManager = new ManagerFactory().GetCallRecordingManager())
                     {
                         UserProfile UserProfile = UserProfileManager1.GetByfkAccountId(Convert.ToInt32(AccountId)).FirstOrDefault();
                         Account acc = AccountManager.GetById(Convert.ToInt32(AccountId));                                      
                         UserProfile CurrentLoggedInUser = UserProfileManager1.GetByfkAccountId(Convert.ToInt32(CurrentAccount.Id)).FirstOrDefault();
                         CallRecording callRecording = CallRecordingManager.GetById(callRecordingId);

                         if (subject.Contains("##password##") || body.Contains("##password##"))
                             password = GetPassword(UserProfile.UserAuthentication.EmailAddress);


                         foreach (MailMergeCode mergeCode in mailMergeCodes)
                         {
                             if (body.Contains(mergeCode.MailMerge)) 
                                 body = Regex.Replace(body, mergeCode.MailMerge, mergeCode.FieldName, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);


                             if (subject.Contains(mergeCode.MailMerge) && !subject.Contains("##password##"))
                                 subject = Regex.Replace(subject, mergeCode.MailMerge, mergeCode.FieldName, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

                         }

                     }
                 }
             }
         }
     }

 }
```

}

But following line makes `##NewUserFirstName##` as `UserProfile.FirstName`

`body = Regex.Replace(body, mergeCode.MailMerge, mergeCode.FieldName, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);`

instead of getting value from `UserProfile.FirstName` which is "Joe Smith"

How can I solve this ?

Comment: have you used string.replace let me know if this solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

Use this code please let me know if you have any problems

```
if (Body.Contains(""##password##""))
 {
 Body = Body.Replace(""##password##"", yourpassword_string);
 }
```

Comment: Hi @Skhurams: I am trying to replace mergeCode.MailMerge with mergeCode.FieldName where mergeCode.MailMerge  is ##NewUserFirstName## and mergeCode.FieldName is UserProfile.FirstName but i want value held by UserProfile.FirstName which is "Joe smith"

Comment: when you add string to subject and body replace string with the code i mentioned